# How to make react to wait until api data is retrieved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I am retrieving the data from an API (using axios) every 15mins and is showing in a table. However, the UI is not waiting until the api data is fetched. What mistake am I doing?  Please find the below code.

```
const INTERVAL_DURATION = 15 * 1000 * 60;


class ApplicationDashboard extends Component {


    state = {
        defaultEnv: 'DIT',
        appsToShow: [],
        appsDataApi: [],
        env: 'DIT',
        selectedEnvs: 'DIT'
    };

    // on change of environment
    handleEnvClick = (selectedButton) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedEnvs: selectedButton
        }, () => {
            this.getAppDataByEnv(this.state.selectedEnvs);
        });
    }

    getAppDataByEnv = (selectedEnv) => {
        console.log("selected env " + selectedEnv);

        this.setState({
            defaultEnv: selectedEnv
        }, () => {
            this.setState({
                appsToShow: this.state.appsDataApi.filter(app => app.env === selectedEnv)
            });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._fetchAppsByIntervals = setInterval(this.getAppHealthDataFromES(), INTERVAL_DURATION);
        this.getAppDataByEnv(this.state.defaultEnv);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // clearInterval(this._fetchAppsByInterval);
        clearInterval(this._fetchAppsByIntervals);

    }

    getAppHealthDataFromES = async () => {

        const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';
        const url = `${BASE_URL}/log/v1/appinfo`;
        await axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({
                    appsDataApi: data
                })
                console.log(this.state.appsDataApi)
            });
    }

    render() {
            return ( <
                    div className = "app-dashboard-main-div" >
                    <
                    div className = "app-dashboard-container" >
                    <
                    div className = "app-dashboard-table-env-main" >
                    <
                    div className = "app-dashboard-label" >
                    Applications <
                    /div>

                    <
                    div className = "EnvGroupButtonsMain" >
                    <
                    button onClick = {
                        () => this.handleEnvClick("DIT")
                    }
                    className = {
                        `${this.state.selectedEnvs==='DIT'?'activeEnv':'inActiveEnv'}`
                    } > DIT < /button> <
                    button onClick = {
                        () => this.handleEnvClick("FIT")
                    }
                    className = {
                        `${this.state.selectedEnvs==='FIT'?'activeEnv':'inActiveEnv'}`
                    } > FIT < /button> <
                    button onClick = {
                        () => this.handleEnvClick("IAT")
                    }
                    className = {
                        `${this.state.selectedEnvs==='IAT'?'activeEnv':'inActiveEnv'}`
                    } > IAT < /button> <
                    button onClick = {
                        () => this.handleEnvClick("PROD")
                    }
                    className = {
                        `${this.state.selectedEnvs==='PROD'?'activeEnv':'inActiveEnv'}`
                    } > PROD < /button> <
                    /div>

                    ...
```

Could someone please help if there is some mistake in the way am invoking using axios async. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `.then` if you are using async/await, try:

```
const response = await axios.get(url);

this.setState({ appsDataApi: response.data }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.appsDataApi)
});
```

You can also refactor the request line like:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(url);
```

And use it as `appsDataApi: data`.

**Update**

If you want to hide the content until the request arrives, you can do something similar:

```
render() {
  return (
    {
      this.state.appsDataApi ?
        // insert your content here
      :
        // add a loader or an empty div here
    }
  )
}
```

Define the `appsDataApi` as `null` in the default state.

Comment: it would look nicer if you destructure the data `const { data } = await axios.get(url);`

Comment: I did the change as suggested, but its not working. I tried to debug and the execution is not getting to 'getAppHealthDataFromES' from componentDidMount. Instead, the page is loading even before the response is fetched.

Comment: Tamas's process should work in retrieving the data, make sure the API call is inside a function that is async "const functionName = async ()=> ".  Could you elaborate on what's not taking place as you'd like? (you have a chart rendered and the chart needs to update every 15 min, so it should show old data until new data is retrieved via axios and state is updated.....which part of this process is failing for you?)